# How to fully pass a List?

Tags: c#

I use a list to contain data parsed from an XML file, using strings as its members:

```
public class ServerList
{
    public string ServerName { set; get; }
    public string ServerReboot { set; get; }
    public string ServerShutdown { set; get; }

    public ServerList()
    {
        ServerName = "";
        ServerReboot = "";
        ServerShutdown = "";
    }
}
```

From the main form I launch an editor form and pass the list into it.  On this editor form the user is able to add or remove entry entries form the list, as well as make changes to parts of the list.  If they click the OK button I want to be able to pull the list form the editor form back into the main form, but if they click Cancel I want these changes to get dropped.  This is the way the editor form is pulled up:

```
    private void mnuEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditor theEditor = new frmEditor();
        theEditor.updatedServerList = theServerList;
        DialogResult res = theEditor.ShowDialog();

        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            theServerList = theEditor.updatedServerList.ToList();
            SetupFilters(GroupOrBatch.Group);
            // other processing to update the main form from the updated list
        }
    }
```

And on the Edit form this is how it is received:

```
public partial class frmEditor : Form
{
    private List<ServerList> myServerList = new List<ServerList>();

    public List<ServerList> updatedServerList
    {
        get { return myServerList; }
        set { myServerList = value.ToList(); }
    }
....
```

What I am finding is that while the list structure appears to be copied to the new variable, the actual data is still linked to the original list.  Even if the user clicks Cancel, and the modified list is not copied back to the original, the original has already been changed.

This leaves me with one of two options - either I can find some way to do a full deep clone of the list to a new one (which can be dropped upon an Cancel), or I remove the Cancel button entirely and have all edits be live.

Comment: So what's your question?  You know what you need to do, either don't allow a cancel or copy the items of the list as well as the list itself.  There's no question there.

Comment: you meant you have a class*, not a list

Comment: `either I can find some way to do a full deep clone of the list to a new one (which can be dropped upon an Cancel), or I remove the Cancel button entirely` - yes, these are your options. Or make your `ServerList` a `struct` so that the copying is [automatically done for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664472%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @FirstStep `private List<ServerList> myServerList = new List<ServerList>`

Comment: An easy way to clone your items would be to change `updatedServerList` setter to: `set { myServerList = value.Select(s => new ServerList() { ServerName = s.ServerName, ServerReboot = S.ServerReboot, ServerShutdown = s.ServerShutdown }).ToList(); }`

Comment: @Pluto ... unless `ServerList` has properties that are also objects.

Comment: @GSerg "I use a list to contain data parsed from an XML file, using strings as its members:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is stored by reference inside the list. The `.ToList()` merely makes a shallow copy of the list with the same references pointing to those `ServerList`. Therefore by making any changes on the **shadow copy**, the original list is still affected.

You need to make a **deep copy** the list, and to pass them around for editing them :

**ServerList::Clone**

```
public class ServerList
{
    // properties...
    // ctor...

    public ServerList Clone()
    {
        return new ServerList
        {
            ServerName = ServerName,
            ServerReboot = ServerReboot,
            ServerShutdown = ServerShutdown,
        });
    }
}
```

**mnuEdit_Click**

```
private void mnuEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmEditor theEditor = new frmEditor();
    theEditor.updatedServerList = theServerList.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToList(); /*changed */
    DialogResult res = theEditor.ShowDialog();

    if (res == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        theServerList = theEditor.updatedServerList; /* changed */
        SetupFilters(GroupOrBatch.Group);
        // other processing to update the main form from the updated list
    }
}
```

Note: The `.ToList()` on `updatedServerList.get` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, since your data set is very small, convert your data to a struct:

```
public struct ServerList
{
    public string ServerName { get; private set; }
    public string ServerReboot { get; private set; }
    public string ServerShutdown { get; private set; }

    public ServerList(string name, string reboot, string shutDown)
    {
        this.ServerName = name;
        this.ServerReboot = reboot;
        this.ServerShutdown = shutDown;
    }
}
```

A `struct` is a value type (as opposed to a reference type), and value semantics will apply to it. Consider the following:

```
var listA = new ServerList("Foo", "Daily", "Never");
var listB = listA;
```

A copy of `listA` and all of its values is stored in `listB`, not a reference. For the strings, copies of the references are made, but strings are immutable anyway, so there's no issue there.

**CON:** structs are supposed to be immutable. Once you initialize them, you can't change their data. Consider that before adopting this solution.